# Connect parent to children in graph structure stored in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV-formatted file like this. The first row of the file is the header. For example, according to column 'tree', and where column 'type' is 'asset', '2' is the parent of '2-1', '2-2', '2-3', '2-4', '2-5', and '2-6'. So, this represents how parents with their children are connected.

```
type,value,tree
asset,804,1
asset,498,2
asset,0,2-1
asset,0,2-2
asset,0,2-3
asset,0,2-4
asset,4981064,2-5
asset,0,2-6
asset,0,3
asset,0,4
asset,980,5
asset,919,5-1
asset,103,5-1-1
asset,699,5-1-2
asset,315,5-1-3
asset,113,5-1-4
asset,378,5-1-5
asset,0,5-1-6
asset,615,5-1-7
asset,101,5-1-8
asset,137,5-1-9
asset,0,5-1-10
asset,0,5-1-11
asset,179,5-1-12
asset,398,5-1-13
asset,608,5-2
asset,496,5-2-1
asset,497,5-2-2
asset,0,5-2-3
asset,111,5-2-4
asset,484,5-2-5
asset,0,5-2-6
asset,237,5-2-7
asset,226,5-2-8
asset,379,5-2-9
asset,0,5-2-10
asset,0,5-2-11
asset,419,5-2-12
asset,340,5-2-13
asset,262,12-4
asset,181,13
asset,539,14
asset,181,15
asset,0,16
asset,533,17
asset,0,18
liability,137,1
liability,312,1-1
liability,0,1-1-1
liability,0,1-1-2
liability,0,1-1-3
liability,0,1-1-4
liability,0,1-1-5
liability,312,1-1-6
liability,591,1-2
liability,413,1-2-1
liability,506,1-2-2
liability,103,1-2-3
liability,237,1-2-4
liability,0,1-2-5
liability,194,1-3
liability,0,1-4
liability,463,1-5
liability,0,1-6
liability,881,1-7
liability,707,2
liability,615,2-1
liability,858,2-2
liability,831,2-3
liability,0,2-4
liability,266,2-5
liability,554,2-6
liability,312,3
liability,400,3-1
liability,105,3-2
liability,352,3-3
liability,0,3-6
liability,0,3-4
liability,316,3-5
revenue,290,1
revenue,283,1-1
revenue,149,1-1-1
revenue,126,1-1-1-1
revenue,836,1-1-1-2
revenue,294,1-1-1-3
revenue,321,1-1-1-4
revenue,835,1-1-1-5
revenue,0,1-1-1-6
revenue,143,1-1-1-7
revenue,101,1-1-1-8
revenue,165,1-1-1-9
revenue,0,1-1-1-10
revenue,0,1-1-1-11
revenue,0,1-1-1-12
revenue,862,1-1-1-13
revenue,512,1-1-2
revenue,512,1-1-2-1
revenue,0,1-1-2-2
revenue,0,1-1-2-3
revenue,175,1-1-3
revenue,0,1-1-3-1
revenue,0,1-1-3-2
revenue,773,1-1-3-3
revenue,0,1-1-3-4
revenue,0,1-1-3-5
revenue,341,1-1-3-6
revenue,0,1-1-3-7
revenue,336,1-1-3-8
revenue,285,1-1-3-9
revenue,703,1-1-3-10
revenue,125,1-1-3-11
revenue,0,1-1-3-12
revenue,0,1-1-3-13
revenue,0,1-1-3-14
revenue,0,1-1-3-15
revenue,570,1-1-3-16
revenue,111,1-1-4
revenue,0,1-1-5
revenue,0,1-1-6
revenue,690,1-2
revenue,690,1-2-1
revenue,0,1-2-1-1
revenue,0,1-2-1-2
revenue,690,1-2-1-3
cost,123,1
cost,110,1-1
cost,109,1-1-1
cost,109,1-1-1-1
cost,0,1-1-1-2
cost,0,1-1-1-3
cost,0,1-1-1-4
cost,0,1-1-1-5
cost,0,1-1-1-6
cost,0,1-1-1-7
cost,654,1-1-2
cost,0,1-1-2-1
cost,0,1-1-2-2
cost,0,1-1-2-3
cost,654,1-1-2-4
cost,127,1-2
cost,917,1-2-1
cost,562,1-2-1-1
cost,355,1-2-1-2
cost,749,1-2-2
cost,607,1-2-2-1
cost,135,1-2-2-2
cost,220,1-2-3
cost,0,1-2-3-1
cost,220,1-2-3-2
cost,574,1-2-4
cost,473,1-2-4-1
cost,100,1-2-4-2
cost,0,1-2-5
cost,0,1-2-5-1
cost,0,1-2-5-2
cost,0,1-2-6
```

I want to write Python code to produce a tuple of the accounting constraints strings like this:

```
('asset_2 == asset_2-1 + asset_2-2 + asset_2-3 + asset_2-4 + asset_2-5 + asset_2-6',
 'asset_5 == asset_5-1 + asset_5-2',
 'asset_5-1 == asset_5-1_1 + asset_5-1-2 + asset_5-1-3 + asset_5-1-4 + asset_5-1-5 + asset_5-1-6 + asset_5-1-7 + asset_5-1-8 + asset_5-1-9 + asset_5-1-10 + asset_5-1-11 + asset_5-1-12 + asset_5-1-13',
...,
'liability_1 == liability_1_1 + liability_1_2 + liability_1_3 + liability_1_4 + liability_1_5 + liability_1_6 + liability_1_7',
...,
'revenue_1 == revenue_1_1 + revenue_1_2',
'revenue_1_1 == revenue_1_1_1 + revenue_1_1_2 + revenue_1_1_3 + revenue_1_1_4 + revenue_1_1_5 + revenue_1_1_6',
...,
'cost_1 == cost_1_1 + cost_1_2',
'cost_1_1 == cost_1_1_1 + cost_1_1_2',
...
)
```

As you can see in the above output, all children are now connected to their parents.

Comment: parent-child connection is understood, but post a fragment of the final expected output for your input sample

Comment: This feels like something that the networkx library would be good at

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The expected output is at the end of the post.

Comment: @MohammadNamakshenas, No. That was a pseudo-code and that is not valid python code. Post a valid expected output

Comment: Dear @RomanPerekhrest, This is why I'm asking for your kind help. I really don't know how to approach the problem in order to find a pseudo-code or the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to assemble a structure of parent/children from the composite names (using prefixes as the hierarchical relationship):

```
with open('csv.txt') as f:      
    csv_lines = f.read().split("\n")

names = ["{0}_{2}".format(*line.split(",")) for line in csv_lines]

grouped = { name:[] for name in names }
grouped.update( (parent,grouped[parent]+[child])      
                for child in names for parent in child.rsplit("-",1)[:1]
                if parent != child and parent in grouped)

result = tuple( parent + " == " + " + ".join(children)
                for parent,children in grouped.items() if children )
```

output:

```
print(*result,sep="\n")

asset_2 == asset_2-1 + asset_2-2 + asset_2-3 + asset_2-4 + asset_2-5 + asset_2-6
asset_5 == asset_5-1 + asset_5-2
asset_5-1 == asset_5-1-1 + asset_5-1-2 + asset_5-1-3 + asset_5-1-4 + asset_5-1-5 + asset_5-1-6 + asset_5-1-7 + asset_5-1-8 + asset_5-1-9 + asset_5-1-10 + asset_5-1-11 + asset_5-1-12 + asset_5-1-13
asset_5-2 == asset_5-2-1 + asset_5-2-2 + asset_5-2-3 + asset_5-2-4 + asset_5-2-5 + asset_5-2-6 + asset_5-2-7 + asset_5-2-8 + asset_5-2-9 + asset_5-2-10 + asset_5-2-11 + asset_5-2-12 + asset_5-2-13
liability_1 == liability_1-1 + liability_1-2 + liability_1-3 + liability_1-4 + liability_1-5 + liability_1-6 + liability_1-7
liability_1-1 == liability_1-1-1 + liability_1-1-2 + liability_1-1-3 + liability_1-1-4 + liability_1-1-5 + liability_1-1-6
liability_1-2 == liability_1-2-1 + liability_1-2-2 + liability_1-2-3 + liability_1-2-4 + liability_1-2-5
liability_2 == liability_2-1 + liability_2-2 + liability_2-3 + liability_2-4 + liability_2-5 + liability_2-6
liability_3 == liability_3-1 + liability_3-2 + liability_3-3 + liability_3-6 + liability_3-4 + liability_3-5
revenue_1 == revenue_1-1 + revenue_1-2
revenue_1-1 == revenue_1-1-1 + revenue_1-1-2 + revenue_1-1-3 + revenue_1-1-4 + revenue_1-1-5 + revenue_1-1-6
revenue_1-1-1 == revenue_1-1-1-1 + revenue_1-1-1-2 + revenue_1-1-1-3 + revenue_1-1-1-4 + revenue_1-1-1-5 + revenue_1-1-1-6 + revenue_1-1-1-7 + revenue_1-1-1-8 + revenue_1-1-1-9 + revenue_1-1-1-10 + revenue_1-1-1-11 + revenue_1-1-1-12 + revenue_1-1-1-13
revenue_1-1-2 == revenue_1-1-2-1 + revenue_1-1-2-2 + revenue_1-1-2-3
revenue_1-1-3 == revenue_1-1-3-1 + revenue_1-1-3-2 + revenue_1-1-3-3 + revenue_1-1-3-4 + revenue_1-1-3-5 + revenue_1-1-3-6 + revenue_1-1-3-7 + revenue_1-1-3-8 + revenue_1-1-3-9 + revenue_1-1-3-10 + revenue_1-1-3-11 + revenue_1-1-3-12 + revenue_1-1-3-13 + revenue_1-1-3-14 + revenue_1-1-3-15 + revenue_1-1-3-16
revenue_1-2 == revenue_1-2-1
revenue_1-2-1 == revenue_1-2-1-1 + revenue_1-2-1-2 + revenue_1-2-1-3
cost_1 == cost_1-1 + cost_1-2
cost_1-1 == cost_1-1-1 + cost_1-1-2
cost_1-1-1 == cost_1-1-1-1 + cost_1-1-1-2 + cost_1-1-1-3 + cost_1-1-1-4 + cost_1-1-1-5 + cost_1-1-1-6 + cost_1-1-1-7
cost_1-1-2 == cost_1-1-2-1 + cost_1-1-2-2 + cost_1-1-2-3 + cost_1-1-2-4
cost_1-2 == cost_1-2-1 + cost_1-2-2 + cost_1-2-3 + cost_1-2-4 + cost_1-2-5 + cost_1-2-6
cost_1-2-1 == cost_1-2-1-1 + cost_1-2-1-2
cost_1-2-2 == cost_1-2-2-1 + cost_1-2-2-2
cost_1-2-3 == cost_1-2-3-1 + cost_1-2-3-2
cost_1-2-4 == cost_1-2-4-1 + cost_1-2-4-2
cost_1-2-5 == cost_1-2-5-1 + cost_1-2-5-2
```

*Note: based on your example, I intentionally excluded parents that don't have any children.  Those could be included easily by removing the `if children` condition from the result comprehension.*

Comment: Thanks. This code is not returning any result. I only added these two lines to the beginning of your code:
`with open('csv.txt') as f:

    csv_lines = f.readlines()` and `csv.txt` is the raw csv file data as stated in my question.

Comment: I assumed you would be able to get the data in the csv_lines list using your own code but, for future readers I added the two lines to my example (I was testing this without reading a file cause i'm lazy)

Comment: @alain-tan, I got an error: `IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple` for this line `names = ["{0}_{2}".format(*line.split(",")) for line in csv_lines]`

Comment: check the content of your file, there's probably a line with a missing comma.  The error corresponds to the result of .split(",") not returning at least 3 values. (for example an empty line at the end or somewhere else)

Comment: @alain-tan, many thanks. At the end of the file, there was an extra `\n`.